# display the li tags to the middle part of a div tag

Tags: css, html, position, center

I have been reviewing different solutions on positioning the elements to the middle part of a div tag it's easier when being done for text cause I could use this code "text-align:center" but what if I have this sample code below:

```
<ul class="gauges" style="">
                <li style="">
                        <form onclick="this.submit()" style="cursor: pointer;" method="post" action="http://dev1089.zbglobal.com/transcript/index.php">
                            <div class="subject_progress_body" style="">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="5" name="category_id">
                                    <div class="progressbar_outer_block jgauge" style="background: url(&quot;http://dev1089.zbglobal.com/transcript/gauge/jgauge_face_default.png&quot;) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 36px; width: 160px; height: 114px; z-index: 0;" id="progressbar_outer_0_block"><canvas id="progressbar_outer_0_block-canvas-ticks" width="160" height="114" style="z-index: 2;"></canvas><p class="tick-label" style="left: 1px; top: 76px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">0</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 11px; top: 44px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">20</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 38px; top: 25px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">40</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 72px; top: 25px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">60</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 99px; top: 44px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">80</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 109px; top: 76px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">100</p><p class="label" id="progressbar_outer_0_block-label" style="left: 0px; top: 69px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 4; margin-top: 20px; font-family: Arial Black,Arial;"><strong>0</strong> %</p><span style="display: inline-block; width: 160px; height: 160px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 1px;" id="progressbar_outer_0_block-needle" class="needle"><canvas height="226" width="226" style="position: relative; left: -33.1371px; top: -33.1371px;"></canvas></span></div>
                                    <center>
                                        <div class="course_description_block">
                                            <p style="text-align: center;">Get Started</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </center>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </li>

                <li style="">
                        <form onclick="this.submit()" style="cursor: pointer;" method="post" action="http://dev1089.zbglobal.com/transcript/index.php">
                            <div class="subject_progress_body" style="">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="6" name="category_id">
                                    <div class="progressbar_outer_block jgauge" style="background: url(&quot;http://dev1089.zbglobal.com/transcript/gauge/jgauge_face_default.png&quot;) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 36px; width: 160px; height: 114px; z-index: 0;" id="progressbar_outer_1_block"><canvas id="progressbar_outer_1_block-canvas-ticks" width="160" height="114" style="z-index: 2;"></canvas><p class="tick-label" style="left: 1px; top: 76px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">0</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 11px; top: 44px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">20</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 38px; top: 25px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">40</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 72px; top: 25px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">60</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 99px; top: 44px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">80</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 109px; top: 76px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">100</p><p class="label" id="progressbar_outer_1_block-label" style="left: 0px; top: 69px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 4; margin-top: 20px; font-family: Arial Black,Arial;"><strong>0</strong> %</p><span style="display: inline-block; width: 160px; height: 160px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 1px;" id="progressbar_outer_1_block-needle" class="needle"><canvas height="226" width="226" style="position: relative; left: -33.1371px; top: -33.1371px;"></canvas></span></div>
                                    <center>
                                        <div class="course_description_block">
                                            <p style="text-align: center;">Make A Plan</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </center>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </li>

                <li style="">
                        <form onclick="this.submit()" style="cursor: pointer;" method="post" action="http://dev1089.zbglobal.com/transcript/index.php">
                            <div class="subject_progress_body" style="">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="8" name="category_id">
                                    <div class="progressbar_outer_block jgauge" style="background: url(&quot;http://dev1089.zbglobal.com/transcript/gauge/jgauge_face_default.png&quot;) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 36px; width: 160px; height: 114px; z-index: 0;" id="progressbar_outer_2_block"><canvas id="progressbar_outer_2_block-canvas-ticks" width="160" height="114" style="z-index: 2;"></canvas><p class="tick-label" style="left: 1px; top: 76px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">0</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 11px; top: 44px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">20</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 38px; top: 25px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">40</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 72px; top: 25px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">60</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 99px; top: 44px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">80</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 109px; top: 76px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">100</p><p class="label" id="progressbar_outer_2_block-label" style="left: 0px; top: 69px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 4; margin-top: 20px; font-family: Arial Black,Arial;"><strong>0</strong> %</p><span style="display: inline-block; width: 160px; height: 160px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 1px;" id="progressbar_outer_2_block-needle" class="needle"><canvas height="226" width="226" style="position: relative; left: -33.1371px; top: -33.1371px;"></canvas></span></div>
                                    <center>
                                        <div class="course_description_block">
                                            <p style="text-align: center;"> Make It Happen</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </center>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </li>

                <li style="">
                        <form onclick="this.submit()" style="cursor: pointer;" method="post" action="http://dev1089.zbglobal.com/transcript/index.php">
                            <div class="subject_progress_body" style="">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="category_id">
                                    <div class="progressbar_outer_block jgauge" style="background: url(&quot;http://dev1089.zbglobal.com/transcript/gauge/jgauge_face_default.png&quot;) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 36px; width: 160px; height: 114px; z-index: 0;" id="progressbar_outer_3_block"><canvas id="progressbar_outer_3_block-canvas-ticks" width="160" height="114" style="z-index: 2;"></canvas><p class="tick-label" style="left: 1px; top: 76px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">0</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 11px; top: 44px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">20</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 38px; top: 25px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">40</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 72px; top: 25px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">60</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 99px; top: 44px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">80</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 109px; top: 76px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">100</p><p class="label" id="progressbar_outer_3_block-label" style="left: 0px; top: 69px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 4; margin-top: 20px; font-family: Arial Black,Arial;"><strong>0</strong> %</p><span style="display: inline-block; width: 160px; height: 160px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 1px;" id="progressbar_outer_3_block-needle" class="needle"><canvas height="226" width="226" style="position: relative; left: -33.1371px; top: -33.1371px;"></canvas></span></div>
                                    <center>
                                        <div class="course_description_block">
                                            <p style="text-align: center;">Business Basics</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </center>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </li>

                <li style="">
                        <form onclick="this.submit()" style="cursor: pointer;" method="post" action="http://dev1089.zbglobal.com/transcript/index.php">
                            <div class="subject_progress_body" style="">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="category_id">
                                    <div class="progressbar_outer_block jgauge" style="background: url(&quot;http://dev1089.zbglobal.com/transcript/gauge/jgauge_face_default.png&quot;) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 36px; width: 160px; height: 114px; z-index: 0;" id="progressbar_outer_4_block"><canvas id="progressbar_outer_4_block-canvas-ticks" width="160" height="114" style="z-index: 2;"></canvas><p class="tick-label" style="left: 1px; top: 76px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">0</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 11px; top: 44px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">20</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 38px; top: 25px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">40</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 72px; top: 25px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">60</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 99px; top: 44px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">80</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 109px; top: 76px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">100</p><p class="label" id="progressbar_outer_4_block-label" style="left: 0px; top: 69px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 4; margin-top: 20px; font-family: Arial Black,Arial;"><strong>0</strong> %</p><span style="display: inline-block; width: 160px; height: 160px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 1px;" id="progressbar_outer_4_block-needle" class="needle"><canvas height="226" width="226" style="position: relative; left: -33.1371px; top: -33.1371px;"></canvas></span></div>
                                    <center>
                                        <div class="course_description_block">
                                            <p style="text-align: center;">Engaging Colleagues &amp; Leading People</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </center>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </li>

                <li style="">
                        <form onclick="this.submit()" style="cursor: pointer;" method="post" action="http://dev1089.zbglobal.com/transcript/index.php">
                            <div class="subject_progress_body" style="">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="category_id">
                                    <div class="progressbar_outer_block jgauge" style="background: url(&quot;http://dev1089.zbglobal.com/transcript/gauge/jgauge_face_default.png&quot;) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 36px; width: 160px; height: 114px; z-index: 0;" id="progressbar_outer_5_block"><canvas id="progressbar_outer_5_block-canvas-ticks" width="160" height="114" style="z-index: 2;"></canvas><p class="tick-label" style="left: 1px; top: 76px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">0</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 11px; top: 44px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">20</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 38px; top: 25px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">40</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 72px; top: 25px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">60</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 99px; top: 44px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">80</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 109px; top: 76px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">100</p><p class="label" id="progressbar_outer_5_block-label" style="left: 0px; top: 69px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 4; margin-top: 20px; font-family: Arial Black,Arial;"><strong>0</strong> %</p><span style="display: inline-block; width: 160px; height: 160px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 1px;" id="progressbar_outer_5_block-needle" class="needle"><canvas height="226" width="226" style="position: relative; left: -33.1371px; top: -33.1371px;"></canvas></span></div>
                                    <center>
                                        <div class="course_description_block">
                                            <p style="text-align: center;">Managing People, Products &amp; Processes</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </center>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </li>

                <li style="">
                        <form onclick="this.submit()" style="cursor: pointer;" method="post" action="http://dev1089.zbglobal.com/transcript/index.php">
                            <div class="subject_progress_body" style="">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="4" name="category_id">
                                    <div class="progressbar_outer_block jgauge" style="background: url(&quot;http://dev1089.zbglobal.com/transcript/gauge/jgauge_face_default.png&quot;) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 36px; width: 160px; height: 114px; z-index: 0;" id="progressbar_outer_6_block"><canvas id="progressbar_outer_6_block-canvas-ticks" width="160" height="114" style="z-index: 2;"></canvas><p class="tick-label" style="left: 1px; top: 76px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">0</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 11px; top: 44px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">20</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 38px; top: 25px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">40</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 72px; top: 25px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">60</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 99px; top: 44px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">80</p><p class="tick-label" style="left: 109px; top: 76px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 3;">100</p><p class="label" id="progressbar_outer_6_block-label" style="left: 0px; top: 69px; color: white; display: block; z-index: 4; margin-top: 20px; font-family: Arial Black,Arial;"><strong>0</strong> %</p><span style="display: inline-block; width: 160px; height: 160px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 1px;" id="progressbar_outer_6_block-needle" class="needle"><canvas height="226" width="226" style="position: relative; left: -33.1371px; top: -33.1371px;"></canvas></span></div>
                                    <center>
                                        <div class="course_description_block">
                                            <p style="text-align: center;">Influencing the Organization</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </center>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </li>
</ul>
```

I'm using jgauge for this element here is the sample screenshot of what it looks like on the site:

[image: Sample Screenshot]

The number of gauges is dynamic and once the number of elements being displayed is less than four it should be positioned at the middle both the gauge and it's text description as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: margin:auto wont work because the width isn't set (i think), can you add different classes for the number of gauges being shown? like <div class="gauge3"> would show 3? if so, i think i can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.gauges { text-align:center }
.gauges li { display:inline-block }
```

*Also, you should note that your HTML is not syntactically valid for HTML4, but is valid for HTML5 (proposed); make sure you're describing your document with the correct DOCTYPE.*

Comment: yup the plugin automatically does it's work when the browser doesn't support html5 it will convert the tags to something that would be compatible to it's earlier versions, the gauges are actually generated by the plugin. :)

Comment: Keep in mind that this technique is buggy in IE7. It works fine for elements that are inline by default but unfortunately list items are block level by default.

Answer (score -1):

Typically, you can center a div within another block level element by using margins.

```
.course_description_block {
    margin: auto;
}
```

The text within the divs can be positioned using plain old text-align: center.